# Are there principled ways of tuning a neural network in case of overfitting and underfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, hyperparameter-optimization, regularization, underfitting

Whenever I tune my neural network, I usually take the common approach of defining some layers with some neurons.

- If it overfits, I reduce the layers, neurons, add dropout, utilize regularisation.
- If it underfits, I do the other way around.

But it sometimes feels illogical doing all these. So, is there a more principled way of tuning a neural network (i.e. find the optimal number of layers, neurons, etc., in a principled and mathematical sound way), in case it overfits or underfits?

Comment: [How is neural architecture search performed?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12434/2444) may be helpful.